# Can I move the keyboard selector button?

Tags: keyboard, 7.0-nougat, customization

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8+. The way that I naturally grip the phone, combined with the practically bezel-less display, means that I'm often hitting the keyboard selection button by accident while I'm typing one-handed.

[image]

Is there any way to move this button to the left side of the screen, or elsewhere, so I'm less likely to hit it on accident?

Comment: Here's a [recent article on XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-change-your-nav-bar-icons-or-re-arrange-the-buttons-without-root/) that touches the topic of navbar customization in Nougat, but unfortunately, it will not work for non-native implementations such as Samsung's. Just for reference.

Comment: I guess I'll have to wait for Android O and see if Samsung brings that in.